# Crashed: com.apple.main-thread when setting value on NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, today-extension

I have the following code in my Today extension view controller:

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults? = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: kAppGroupName)
if defaults != nil {
    if myNsManagedObject != nil {
        defaults!.setDouble(myNsManagedObject!.doubleField, forKey: "key_name")
    }
}
```

However, I am getting crash reports on the `setDouble` call, though I have not been able to reproduce it myself. What could possibly cause the following crash?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001000b1da4

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  today                          0x1000b1da4 specialized TodayViewController.updateViews(NWXForecastRecord?) -> () (TodayViewController.swift:249)
1  today                          0x1000ad5e0 @objc TodayViewController.viewWillAppear(Bool) -> () (TodayViewController.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x186cd1374 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 628
3  UIKit                          0x186cd10e8 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 156
4  NotificationCenter             0x19443aaa0 -[_NCWidgetViewController viewWillAppear:] + 88
5  UIKit                          0x186cd1374 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 628
6  UIKit                          0x186cd10e8 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 156
7  UIKit                          0x1874d8be8 -[_UIViewServiceViewControllerOperator __hostViewWillAppear:inInterfaceOrientation:traitCollection:statusBarHeight:underlapsStatusBar:completionHandler:] + 568
8  CoreFoundation                 0x181b60a60 __invoking___ + 144
9  CoreFoundation                 0x181a58488 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 284
10 CoreFoundation                 0x181a5cdb0 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 60
11 UIKit                          0x1875acbcc -[_UIViewServiceImplicitAnimationDecodingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 268
12 CoreFoundation                 0x181b5ea1c ___forwarding___ + 408
13 CoreFoundation                 0x181a5cc5c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
14 CoreFoundation                 0x181b60a60 __invoking___ + 144
15 CoreFoundation                 0x181a58488 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 284
16 CoreFoundation                 0x181a5cdb0 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 60
17 UIKit                          0x18752222c -[_UIQueueingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 372
18 CoreFoundation                 0x181b5ea1c ___forwarding___ + 408
19 CoreFoundation                 0x181a5cc5c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
20 CoreFoundation                 0x181b60a60 __invoking___ + 144
21 CoreFoundation                 0x181a58488 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 284
22 CoreFoundation                 0x181a5cdb0 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 60
23 CoreFoundation                 0x181b5ea1c ___forwarding___ + 408
24 CoreFoundation                 0x181a5cc5c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
25 CoreFoundation                 0x181b60a60 __invoking___ + 144
26 CoreFoundation                 0x181a58488 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 284
27 FrontBoardServices             0x1834fb7ac __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
28 FrontBoardServices             0x1834fb618 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 168
29 FrontBoardServices             0x1834fb9c8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
30 CoreFoundation                 0x181b1109c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
31 CoreFoundation                 0x181b10b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
32 CoreFoundation                 0x181b0e830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
33 CoreFoundation                 0x181a38c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
34 GraphicsServices               0x183320088 GSEventRunModal + 180
35 UIKit                          0x186d22088 UIApplicationMain + 204
36 libxpc.dylib                   0x1817fcce0 _xpc_objc_main + 784
37 libxpc.dylib                   0x1817fe9dc xpc_main + 200
38 Foundation                     0x18261bd60 service_connection_handler + 170
39 PlugInKit                      0x188e5ec48 -[PKService run] + 544
40 PlugInKit                      0x188e5e8dc +[PKService main] + 56
41 PlugInKit                      0x188e5ec6c +[PKService _defaultRun:arguments:] + 20
42 libextension.dylib             0x18242e058 NSExtensionMain + 64
43 libdispatch.dylib              0x1815d68b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: Carloshwa did you get anywhere with this crash? I'm seeing a similar crash in my own code.

Comment: Updating my code Swift 3 has made the crash go away:
`defaults!.set(myNsManagedObject!.doubleField, forKey: "key_name")`